# GET http://url/route?id=clinic_id 404 (Not Found) in AJAX

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, laravel

I am showing the price table of all services in my Laravel website. Now I want to change the price table according to the selection from the service dropdown list. That's why I am using AJAX to call my controller according to the change of service dropdown list and show the price table of selected service.

But I am getting an error in **AJAX**

> jquery-3.2.1.min.js:4 GET http://my_url/route_name?id=clinic_id 404 (Not Found)

**HTML**

```
<form id="check_pricelist_form" method="get">
   <select class="form-control search_pricelist_Field col-md-4" id="clinic_id_pricelist" name="clinic_id">
       <option value="0">All</option>

       @if(count($_SESSION['clinic']) > 0)

          @foreach($_SESSION['clinic'] as $data)    
              <option value="{{ $data->id }}">{{ $data->name }}</option>
          @endforeach

       @endif

   </select>
</form>
```

**Script**

```
$( "#clinic_id_pricelist" ).change(function() {
        var clinic_id = $('#clinic_id_pricelist').val();

        $.get('clinic-price-list', { id: "clinic_id"}, //getting error in this line
        function(returnedData){
             console.log(returnedData);
        });

    });
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/clinic-price-list/{name}','PriceListController@detail');
```

How to solve it ? Thanks in advance

Comment: clinic-price-list is the name of the route?

Comment: Can you show your route?

Comment: @barghouthi .....yes

Comment: @Nirali....route added to the post

Comment: what should {name} be?

Comment: @barghouthi....`{name}` is used for passing parameter(clinic id) through route

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try with

```
$.get('clinic-price-list/clinic_id', //getting error in this line
    function(returnedData){
         console.log(returnedData);
    });
```

### Option 1

**Passing as a request parameter**

If you pass clinic_id is a get parameter your url should be like `http://url/clinic-price-list?id=clinic_id`.

**Controller**

```
public function detail(Request $request){
  $id = $request->input('id');
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/clinic-price-list','PriceListController@detail');
```

**JS**

```
$.get('clinic-price-list', { id: "clinic_id"},
```

---

### Option 2

**Passing as URL Parameters**

If you pass clinic id as a url parameter your url should be like `http://url/clinic-price-list/clinic_id`

**Controller**

```
public function detail(Request $request,$id){
  //$id is the clinic_id
```

**Route**

```
Route::get('/clinic-price-list/{name}','PriceListController@detail');
```

**JS**

```
$.get('clinic-price-list/clinic_id',
```

Comment: Ya now it's ok....But I have already use `$.get('clinic-price-list', { id: "clinic_id"}` this format in another project and no error there. But for this project your's format is doing the job. I accept your ans with little bit change

Answer (score 1):

```
$.get(`clinic-price-list/${clinic_id}`, 
    function(returnedData){
         console.log(returnedData);
    });
```

you need to put the name in the route. use ``` `` ``` and not `""` or `''`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your route is working.
Can you navigate to http://my_url/route_name?id=clinic_id directly?

If its working, make sure your request URL is correct.

$("#clinic_id_pricelist").change(function () {

```
var clinic_id = $('#clinic_id_pricelist').val();
var url = "/my_url/route_name";     //  <- CHANGE THIS TO THE CORRECT URL
$.get(url, {
    id: clinic_id                           
}, function (returnedData) {
    console.log(returnedData);
});
```

});